# auto expansion only possible with scalable fonts caused by siunitx

Tags: miktex, siunitx

**english (german version below):** I have this LaTex code from a template, I have strongly minimized the preamble, because in the original preamble about 100 different packages and functions are included or defined. Whenever I use \si{\ohm} in the text to create an Ohm character I get the error message "auto expansion is only possible with scalable fonts". However, it also depends a bit on the place where I insert the Ohm character, at the end for example it works, but it doesn't belong there.

**german:** Ich habe diesen LaTex-Code aus einer Vorlage, die Präambel habe ich stark minimiert, da in der ursprünglichen Präambel ca. 100 verschiedene Pakete und Funktionen eingebunden bzw. definiert werden. Immer wenn ich \si{\ohm} im Text verwende, um ein Ohm-Zeichen zu erzeugen bekomme ich die Fehlermeldung "auto expansion is only possible with scalable fonts". Allerdings hängt das auch ein bisschen vom Ort ab, an dem ich das Ohm-Zeichen einfüge, am Ende zum Beispiel funktioniert es, da gehört es allerdings nicht hin.

```
\documentclass[%
%enabledeprecatedfontcommands,% Kapitälchen (\sc) wird trotzdem unterstützt
paper=A4,               % Papierformat
fontsize=11pt,          % Zeichensatzgroesse (Koma-Script)
]
{scrartcl}              % Dokumentklasse (alternativ scrartcl oder scrreprt, Koma-Script)

% deutsches Fontencoding, T1 Schriften
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 
% deutsche Trennungsregeln, deutsche Zusatzbefehle
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
 
% Schriftfamilie ComputerModern Bright (serifenlos)
\usepackage{cmbright}
 
% optischer Randausgleich (verschiedene Buchstaben, Satzzeichen, Bindestriche
% etc. werden leicht in den Seitenrand verschoben); automatische Skalierung von
% Buchstaben zur Verbesserung des Blocksatzes
\usepackage[tracking=true,spacing=true,kerning=true,final]{microtype}

% \mathsf fuer cmbright richtig definieren
% (sonst wird bei \mathsf CM-SansSerif verwendet)
\renewcommand{\mathsf}[1]{\,\mathrm{#1}}
 
\usepackage[locale=DE]{siunitx}              % Paket zum Setzen von Einheiten und zur Formatierung von Zahlen


%Dieses SI-Zechen durch beliebigen Text ersetzen und die Fehlermeldung verschwindet:
%\si{\ohm}           


\begin{document}

\section{Oberflächenwiderstand}
Der spezifische Oberflächenwiderstand berechnet sich nach der Formel.
Dieses PVC wurde anschließend im Wärmeschrank langsam auf 40°C
erwärmt. Erwartbar wäre dadurch eine Verringerung des Widerstands.
Tatsächlich stieg der Widerstand aber auf einen Wert von 208 \si{\ohm} an.
Der spezifische Oberflächenwiderstand berechnet sich nach der Formel.
Der spezifische Oberflächenwiderstand berechnet sich nach der Formel.
Der spezifische Oberflächenwiderstand berechnet sich nach der Formel.

\end{document}
```

**Thank you for answers!**

Comment: Unrelated: The `\si` macro is deprecated in version 3 of `siunitx`. You should use `\unit{\ohm}`. But actually, you should even use `\qty{208}{\ohm}`. That's the whole point of `siunitx`.

Comment: looks as if the hfbright package is not installed. Check in the miktex package manager.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I'm getting the same error by just loading `microtype` and with `hfbright` installed. No `babel`, no `fontenc`, no `siunitx`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel the example uses type1 fonts for me and works. if you have miktex and hfbright is installed, try if it works if you remake the map files (in the console, user mode, in the tasks menu)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel `\unit{\ohm}` and `\qty{208}{\ohm}` are unfortunately not working too.

Comment: Thanks @Ulrike Fischer! I have installed hfbright (cm-super was already installed) in the MikTex-console and now it works!

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround for my problem, its maybe not perfect, but OK in my case. I use the package `\usepackage{textgreek}` in the preamble and the command `\textOmega` in the text.

Comment: the error means that you are using bitmap fonts somewhere, and you only need to install the type1 version to get it working. So check in the miktex console if hfbright and cm-super is installed.